# What is the scientific name of this butterfly?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I have this  butterfly but I don't know its scientific name. I think that it's a common butterfly which can be seen everywhere (btw, I'm in Taiwan.) Thanks for your help :D

[image]

Comment: Could you give us an indication of the size of the butterfly and the time of year you saw it?

Comment: If it's a common butterfly, can you ask locals for the common name? That will give us more to go on.

Comment: Your specimen is in very poor shape. did the inner lower wings have have a small 'eye' two thirds of the way down? It may be very insignificant, or difficult to find, on some specimens.

Comment: Maybe common in your locality, is it common throughout world?

Comment: For a species-identification question, size-mention is a must. At least approximate size.

Answer (score 5):

With the information given, I have to say I think it's a [Spangle, *Papilio protenor*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papilio_protenor) of the [swallowtail family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallowtail_butterfly), probably a male.

It also is listed on the [butterflies of Taiwan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_butterflies_of_Taiwan).

See pictures for comparison:

[image][image]

........................Male...............................................female............................................................................